# May the lead role actors be used to fill spaces if needed?

Tags: film-techniques, production

Several scenes in a movie require a lot of people to appear on-screen. For example a scene of a party where it needs a lot of people to appear together. I heard crews of the production unit and even often their kith and kin are used to fill the space as random people. Now my question is **are heroes or heroins who are cast as lead role in a film used to fill the space if they don't have direct shots in that particular scene?**

This question popped into my mind when I saw a picture in Facebook where the uploader claims "Heath Ledger" is used to fill space in a scene in "The Dark Knight". Here is the picture he uploaded:

[image: Is Heath really there?]

Now nobody in that group could tell whether it is true or not. I am not interested about this particular picture because this is hard to know about this particular scene. But I want to know if people with so much importance can be used this way.

Comment: Common sense says *NO*, since this would be absolute total rubbish to do for the filmmarkers. Really, give that *Facebook* idiot a big thumb down.

Answer (score 2):

no, not unless they do not have a direct shot. The ramifications of having something such as this - the **joker** being open, without makeup in Bruce's hotel? Unless this was all done deliberately (if the picture is true).

Normally if such people are used as extras (they are used a lot of times) the editing department works hard to check that their faces or bodies do not appear in any recognizable way for the audience who is seeing the edited film.